# How can I access a log4net logs folder for an azure app service with a readonly user

Tags: c#, azure, log4net, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I can access the log4net log folder via KUDU.  BUT KUDU requires contributor access.  I want to be able to access or download UAT/PROD logs without write permissions.  I'd prefer to avoid going the route of an FTP. My user can navigate the azure portal, resource groups, and see the app service, but does not have console access for an app service.  Is what I'm trying to achieve possible and how?

Comment: A better way for that would be to pump your logs to AppInsights for better visibility. Or you can store your logs on Azure Storage rather than on attached storage for app service.

Comment: Don't have access to the azure storage explorer blade, so I might have to pump them into insights

Comment: AppInsights is a lot better option than storage. Your logs from flat files become actual diagnostic tools without having to parse them by hand.

Comment: @trailmax does app insights store the logs as a flat structure somewhere?

Comment: I don't know how it is stored, but you can configure it to export to a blob storage. Frankly, I never needed to look on logs outside of AppInisights query engine - it is like SQL on drugs, but for logs. Everything I ever wanted to see in logs - I could see there, plus graphs and alerting. It is more powerful than sliced bread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per trailmax mentioned, the [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview) is the easy and convenient way to collect logs / query logs. We recommend using Application Insights for this case.

Install the related application insights sdk(like [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/)), [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender/), and with other little configuration, then application insights can work well for your site.

This is just a suggestion, but if you have any issues about this, please leave a comment here(and provide more information like it's a .NET core or .NET framework project).

Comment: does app insights store my log4net logs in a blob container? and can I see that container?  We have both .net 4.6.2 projects and .net core 3. appinsights is configured for blob storage and I can see and query logs via log analytics. But I'm wondering where they are stored.

Comment: @terrencep, by default, the application insights(assume you have configured log4net to float to app insights) does not store data into blob, unless you create a [Continuous Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry#setup) and specify a blob container. But the limitation is that you only get data that arrives after you create the export.